# Browser stuck on loading audio files

Tags: html, audio

I have some audio files wav and one mp3, but they seem to block Firefox. 
The network tab of FireBug shows the GET request, and how the files are at 0B, and there is the spinning wheel, just spinning there.
The mp3 file is one of the ones not loading and another one is a wav, which is weird because other wav files load just fine.
I tried converting the mp3 to a ogg, then firefox gets stuck at 13KB, and the same happens to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to outdated or disabled plugins in your browsers. I had similar experience with a .wmv file in firefox. It wouldn't play unless I fixed the faulty VLC plugin.  It did work well with IE 11 and Opera 20 though.

If the problem is caused only when you use a specific file, this indicates that the file might not have been encoded properly.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem since, but havent got any closer :( I get different results on different machines, but this sums it up: http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/5D/14/6088af362ca55d14.png Sometimes it even loads... Didn't find anything helpful on the internet either.